# Mono: MONO_THEME has no effect under Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, mono, themes

I am not entirely sure whether MONO_THEME is supposed to do anything for WinForms applications running under Ubuntu, but I got the impression that I should be able to enable GNOME-like looks by using it. I can't get it to do that though.

Here's what I tried:

```
export MONO_THEME=visualstyles
mono MyApp.exe

export MONO_THEME=clearlooks
mono MyApp.exe

export MONO_THEME=nice
mono MyApp.exe
```

But there was exactly zero effect on my application's appearance. I do call Application.EnableVisualStyles() first thing in my code.

How do I enable the themes in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These were removed several years ago as they were not maintained.

Is there some place that still documents these?  If it's somewhere on Mono's site, I would like to remove them.

Comment: Only here: http://www.mono-project.com/FAQ:_Winforms which only mentions "visualstyles". If they are not supported it would probably help to have a page that says this - it will show up in google and help everyone who finds these values via other websites and blogs.

Comment: So there's no simple way of styling WinForms controls to look somewhat like GNOME then?

Comment: The FAQ said it was for Windows only, however I rewrote it to reinforce that fact.

There is no way to automatically style WinForms controls to look like GNOME without handling all the painting yourself.